# My new laptop is lagging

Tags: windows-10, laptop, touchpad, lenovo-laptop, window

I've bought a new laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad P52s, without OS) and installed Windows 10 on it, I've also installed all drivers recommeded by Lenovo.
But I recognized some weird problems:

- Scrolling via touchpad doesn't work sometimes, but mouse movements and clicking are working
- Mouse is lagging sometimes (e. g. opening the Snipping Tools is enough)
- Some Windows Effects are lagging or even stucking (after creating a file via context menu the entry I clicked on remains on the screen… I've fixed it by disabling the fading out effect there)
- Fortnite is lagging on low to middle graphics
- Command line processes are hanging (e. g. python programs or node.js programs), they resume to work when I press Ctrl + C
- I can't open Windows Store, it's closing directly while opening

I didn't have ANY of those problems with my four years old laptop, which is significantly worse regarding to the specs. So I suspect a connection between these problems.

The device manger doesn't show any problems, and build-in troubleshooting doesn't recognize any problems as well.

Any idea where this kind of problems could come from?

Comment: Have all Windows 10 updates completed? Does Task Manager show any process using much CPU time?

Comment: I'm on Version 1803 (Build 17134.345), CPU seems ok most of the time (< 10 %). But memory is mostly around 50 percent used (i.e. 8 / 16 GB), with Chrome at the top with 2 GB, all other processes are using less than 200 MB (I'm wondering if they really sum up to the remaining 5 GB ...).

Comment: Do you get lagging when you boot from a Linux https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/ LiveUSB? Please try that for diagnostic purposes to rule out a hardware fault. When you've tested that, click on [edit] above to the left and add the result to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform a clean boot to see if the issue still exists.

[How to perform a clean boot in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows)

If so, try reinstalling the touchpad driver, power management driver and motherboard driver according to Lenovo official website.

If the above is not helpful, it is recommended that we re-download all the drivers to the D drive on the Lenovo official website, then reinstall the operating system and then install all the drivers.

If all above still does not work, we may need to contact Lenovo manufacturers to check if it is a hardware problem.